# How to GROUP BY date,date's format is nvarchar

Tags: sql

for example:
mydate is nvarchar(20)

```
mydate
-------------
2011/08/04 10:14:47
2011/07/20 15:00:00
2011/07/20 22:15:59
2011/08/04 13:17:33
```

**how to group up by date**

for example:

```
mydate
------------
2011/08/04
2011/07/20
```

Comment: Which database system do you use?

Comment: Dates should not be stored as strings, if you must store them as strings at least use an unambiguous and sortable date format, Finally why `nvarchar(20)`? They will never contain any non ASCII characters.

Comment: @Martin - Are you sure? It seems possible a date in Arabic or Hebrew script can exist ...

Comment: @Hugh - Well if the OP is planning to also store dates as strings in a mixture of Hebrew and the format in the question then this will just add to their list of problems in doing the `GROUP BY`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming tou're using SQL Server, try this:

```
SELECT LEFT(date_col,10) AS mydate, COUNT(*) 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY LEFT(date_col,10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Exactly the same way as usual should do it. If I'm not mistaken the varchar will sort is alphabetically which is in this case the same. I would also be a good idea to change your database structure to a date instead of a char.

Comment: I agree your point, but the table is set and can't be changed.That's why I'm trying to find solutions base on it. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you can use the following example:

```
select substr(mydate, 1, 10), count(*)
  from mytable
 group by substr(mydate, 1, 10)
```

Comment: Thank U ! I'm using SQL SERVER~

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server - Try this,

```
SELECT convert(varchar, getdate(), 111) AS mydate
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY convert(varchar, getdate(), 111)
```